# How to solve this exp Integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral, 
$$
I = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{z/2 - {\left(z - \ln a\right)^2}/4b} - \mathrm{e}^{z/2 - {\left(z + \ln a\right)^2}/4b}dz
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants. I am not quite sure how to complete those squares.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $$A=\frac{z}{2}-\frac{(z-\log (a))^2}{4 b}=-\frac{z^2}{4 b}+\frac{ (\log (a)+b)}{2 b}z-\frac{\log ^2(a)}{4 b}$$ $$A=-\left(\frac{z^2}{4 b}-\frac{ (\log (a)+b)}{2 b}z+\frac{\log ^2(a)}{4 b} \right)=-\frac 1{4b}\left(z^2-2 (\log (a)+b)z+\log ^2(a)\right)$$ Completing the square and making the appropriate change of variable will make you facing the Gaussian integral.

Comment: @Hardy. You are welcome ! It is always the same trick : expand the square, group terms and arrive to something looking like $a(z^2+bz+c)$.